# Issue with session in Codeigniter database session driver / session driver

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3, database-deadlocks, php-7.3

I have a chat application build with Codeigniter 3.1.11 and jQuery ajax. I'm using database session driver. There was no issue in localhost, but when I have moved it to live server and as per increase in the accessing number of users, I have many issues with the session. One of the issue is its creating multiple session ids for a single user (Means when I'm opening a page inside my browser, its creating around 4 to 6 ids minimum inside the ci_sessions table, sometimes its more than that). And sometimes I have losing the session values (like it's resetting in every ajax call). And I have getting the below error also inside the log file:

```
ERROR - 2020-02-04 13:41:30 --> Query error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction - Invalid query: UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `timestamp` = 1580823690 WHERE `id` = 'e0b75ac252a680d3ec6ad1b8589f4836b89f8bf5'
```

My live sever info:

Apache Version: 2.4.41,
PHP Version: 7.3.13,
MySQL Version: 10.3.18-MariaDB,
Operating System: linux

When I'm posting this, my ci_sessions table contains 478 unique ip addresses and 5105 entries inside the table. Please anyone help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per you limited information, I can only suggest you update the following

```
config['sess_match_ip'] = true;
```

This should solve your multiple session for the same user.